# Play video using jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, video, playback

I have created jsp page for subject.which will display videos dynamically depending on video source stored into database.

I m trying to play videos whose paths are stored in database.
but video isnt playing.

[software-Netbeans][ DB- netbeans java DB]
it shows only video player. and video controls are not working.
i am using google chrome.

will below code produce result??*

**subject.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.sql.*,javax.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">


#righta {
    padding: 1ex; 
    margin: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100px;
    width: 600px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body >

<img src="image/banner.jpg"  width="100%" height="50"/>


<div id="righta">
<fieldset>
<h1>STQA</h1>
</fieldset>
<%  
  //connectivity

     Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/database1","app"," ");
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
Statement st=con.createStatement();

//table- course , column-(coursename,sem,subject,topic,videoid,video)
 ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from course where subject='STQA' ");
        while(rs.next())
        {
             String topic=rs.getString(4);
         String video=rs.getString(6);
            out.print("<h2><font size=5 color=red>NAME</font>:"+topic+"</h2>");


    %>    

      //want to take all videos related to my subject i.e STQA
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="<%=rs.getString("video")%>" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
 </video>

     <%
     }
   %>
  <a href="quiz.jsp"> Quiz</a>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8TVK.jpg).

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors ? why dont you use the servlet to connect database ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - it's bad idea to have datasource related code in JSP page. You should use MVC appraoch with Servlets.

Second, this code:

```
"<%=rs.getString("video")%>"
```

Should look like this:

```
"<%=rs.getString('video')%>"
```

Double quotes handle your expression, you can't use double quotes inside previous double quotes.